# Embedding HTML in an HTML attribute to be displayed by css content:attr()?

Tags: html, css, attributes, html-parsing

I realize the title is hard to understand, but what I'm trying to do is actually really simple. I have a custom HTML attribute called "meaning" and use it for span tags like so like so:

```
<span meaning="A type of fruit">kumquat</span>
```

I then display it when the user hovers over the word kumquat (or whatever) using CSS:

```
[meaning]:hover:after {
    content: attr(meaning);
    //various cosmetic and positioning styles here
}
```

But if I want to embed italics, styled text, etc in the meaning attribute, it just shows up as unparsed HTML when I hover over the link, like so:

```
a kumquat is a type of <a href="en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fruit">fruit</a>
```

I assume this is because browsers (at least not Firefox, which is what I use, and a big enough section of the market that even if it works everywhere else I still can't use that solution) don't parse HTML embedded in HTML attributes even if those attributes are dispayed as text by CSS later. Is there another way to do this, maybe with jQuery?

Comment: using css on attributes are not possible,  just try <span title="<spans style='font-style: bold' >Title</span>" > Content <span>"  - it makes no sense.  It's just not part of the css or html specifications.  You could fake it with jQuery like think tooltip, but then it's in another element. You could do like BBcode to [i]content[/i] and parse that with javascript.

Comment: `content` cannot contain HTML, it can only contain plain-text. If you want to use HTML, you will need a separate child attribute, and JS.